# I keep getting segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I need to add the 3 arrays, called `vetor1`, `vetor2`, `vetor3`, to a big array called `conjunto`, but I keep getting the segmentation fault when I run the code.

I use the function `iniciaiza` to create a 50 position array and to fill this array with 0. Then, in the function `read`, I will read a array (most times the size of the array will be 3) and in the function add, I need to copy the three arrays to the one that I created using `malloc`. In the end I need to print the three arrays and the one with the copy of all the three.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *conjunto;
int *vetor1, *vetor2, *vetor3, n1, n2, n3;
int tam = 50;

void inicializa (int **tconj, int tam)
{
    int i;
    *tconj = (int *) malloc (tam * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        tconj[i] = 0;
    }
}

void read (int **vec, int *n)
{
    int i;
    printf("size of array: ");
    scanf ("%d", n);
    printf("array: \n");
    *vec = (int *) malloc (*n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%d", &(*vec)[i]);
    }
}

void add (int *conjunto, int *vetor1, int *vetor2, int *vetor3, int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    int i, j, k, w;
    int fim1 = (n1 + n2);
    int fim2 = (n1 + n2 + n3);
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        conjunto[i] = vetor1[i];
    }
    for (j = n1; j < fim1; j++)
    {
        conjunto[j] = vetor2[j];
    }
    for (k = fim1; k < fim2; k++)
    {
        conjunto[k] = vetor3[k];
    }
}

void print_array (int *vec, int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", vec[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    inicializa (&conjunto, tam);

    read (&vetor1, &n1);
    read (&vetor2, &n2);
    read (&vetor3, &n3);

    print_array (vetor1, n1);
    print_array (vetor2, n2);
    print_array (vetor3, n3);

    add (conjunto, vetor1, vetor2, vetor3, n1, n2, n3);

    print_array (conjunto, tam);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so **when exactly** does the segfault happen?

Comment: `unused variable 'w' [-Werror=unused-variable]`

Comment: When I run the program, I can read all the three arrays and print them, but the code is not making the copy. I forgot to erase the w.

Comment: Trying to understand what is supposed to do your initialization...

Comment: so does that mean that you fixed your program now?

Comment: What are n1, n2 and n3 initialized to?

Comment: Remove the `for` loop in your initialization. Also you should wait to know the sum n1 + n2 + n3 before initializing. And you can also free() at end of program.

Comment: The void inicializa I just use to set all the positions to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization function is almost good, just a small star is missing:

```
void inicializa (int **tconj, int tam)
{
    int i;
    *tconj = (int *) malloc (tam * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        (*tconj)[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Also you should call it in your main after reading input this way:

```
tam = n1 + n2 + n3;
inicializa (&conjunto, tam);
```

And at end of program, before the `return`, you should add:

```
free(conjunto);
free(v1);
free(v2);
free(v3);
```

Edit: I missed two other bugs in `add()`.

```
void add (int *conjunto, int *vetor1, int *vetor2, int *vetor3, int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int fim1 = (n1 + n2);
    int fim2 = (n1 + n2 + n3);
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        conjunto[i] = vetor1[i];
    }
    for (j = n1; j < fim1; j++)
    {
        conjunto[j] = vetor2[j - n1];
    }
    for (k = fim1; k < fim2; k++)
    {
        conjunto[k] = vetor3[k - fim1];
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Also it won't work if user add funny values (such as zero or negative size arrays), I leave those controls to you.

Comment: Thank you, now I am not getting the segmentation fault :)

Answer (score 1):

In your function `add` you are reading `vetor2[j];` and `vetor3[k];` but `j` and `k` can be out of bound of the `vetor`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < tam; i++)
{
    // This is not doing what you think it is.
    // You are setting some memory locations at and after tconj to zero,
    //  which is not the array you just allocated.  
    // The pointer to array that you just allocated is now 0
    tconj[i] = 0; // pretty sure you mean *tconf[i] 
}
```